# Controlling Identity 2.0, UserManager.AddToRoles() behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC C# app using Identity 2.0.  On a form, I have a mulit-select list of roles to assign a user.  In the controller, I call

```
               IdentityResult rc = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(roleViewModel.UserId, roleViewModel.AssignedRoles);
```

(where roleViewModel.UserId is a GUID, and roleViewModel.AssignedRoles is a string[].

The problem is that if the user is already assigned to a role, the operation fails with "User already in role."  I could iterate through the array and query if the user is already in the role prior to attempting to AddToRole (singular), but I would have thought AddToRoles (plural) would allow me to specify whether to ignore existing membership (I certainly didn't see anything in the online doc).

So, my questions...am I thinking this the wrong way?  Is AddToRoles (plural) mainly intended for Create operations, and I have to iterate/AddToRole (singular) for edit/updates?  Or is there a better way?

**Edit 1:**

What about this idea?

```
    IEnumerable<string> rolesToAdd = roleViewModel.AssignedRoles.Except(userManager.GetRoles(roleViewModel.UserId));
    IEnumerable<string> rolesToRemove = userManager.GetRoles(roleViewModel.UserId).Except(roleViewModel.AssignedRoles);
    IdentityResult rcRemove = await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(roleViewModel.UserId, rolesToRemove.ToArray());
    IdentityResult rcAdd = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(roleViewModel.UserId, rolesToAdd.ToArray());
if (!rcAdd.Succeeded || !rcRemove.Succeeded) { ... }
```

(Yes I know I could re-write that into two lines, I wrote like this for clarity.)

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET MVC 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is quite shallow on the topic:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.usermanagerextensions.addtoroles(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.AddToRoles

You could write your own (extension) method that does the job for you. Batch the requests and incorporate the use of `AddToRole` with previous checking for the user being already in the group. This is not a nice way but a possible work-around.